# How to make a RESTful one parameter form in HTML (/search/query instead of /search?q=query)?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, restful-url

I'd like to make a RESTFUL one-parameter form like [this one](http://beta.jisho.org/) but don't understand how to do it with mere HTML. Do I need some Javascript?

Comment: OK, how to do it frameword-agnosticly with Javascript? Because the example I showed uses no redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place a file in the server root named **.htaccess**. In this file place the following code to enable url rewriting:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?query=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This rule makes every incoming request starting with /search/xxx rewrite internally to search.php?query=xxx

The mod_rewrite module must be enabled on your server.

To let your form submit to this url you will have to rely on javascript as there is no standard way. The example site also does this (I have disabled scripts on the site and the form just posts to a similar ?query=xxx url).

I am not sure if you are using the jQuery library but I'm used to it so much I can't provide you regular javascript but only a jQuery example:

```
$("form#yourForm").submit(function() {
   document.location = $(this).attr("action") + "/" + $("#yourField").val();
   return false;
});
```

Edit: Figured out a framework-agnostic method (as requested): http://jsfiddle.net/8vakU/

Comment: Thanks! But my problem is the reverse: I'd like the client to GET /search/query instead of /search?q=query as in the example I linked to.